# Setting title of a web application's index page using ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I want to dynamically update the title of my web application and append the user name after it. I know this can be done using jquery but wanted to know if there is any ember way of doing it.

My title in app/index.html looks like this

```
<title>XYZ.com</title>
```

but I want to make it look like

```
<title>XYZ.com - User name</title>
```

And the username comes from the ember model `User.name`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
document.title = "test";
```

hope it will help u

Comment: The OP says they already know how to do it, but want to find a cleaner way to do this using Ember.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I am looking is for something more emberish, like in the post http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/document-title-integration-into-ember/3324, but it seems its too convoluted, so couldn't try it

Answer (score 2):

There is an Ember CLI addon for this.

Use 'ember-cli-document-title' for a sane way to manage your document title.

The Readme has excellent usage notes.

**Link to Addon**: https://github.com/kimroen/ember-cli-document-title

Answer (score 0):

Declare one variable in application controller.

```
webName: null
```

and which place u have to change the web application name u modify the controller variable of application controller.

```
this.controllerFor('application').set('webName', yourwebappname);
```

Comment: But it doesn't works in index.html page of the web application as I can't use the application controller property there

Comment: I tried many things finally rolled back to the old way by using document.title itself as suggested by elcid9